# Describe d.ts file for patched 3rd party library

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

guys, need help from TS experts

There is a js library let's say @extended/react that patches the original react with some additional components

The question is how can we describe a TS declaration for this monkey-patched 3rd party
Here is the index.js of that library

```js
const React = require('react');
const reactDom = require('react-dom');
const ExtendedComponent = require('./ExtendedComponent');
React.ExtendedComponent = ExtendedComponent;
React.ReactDom = reactDom;

// Exporting patched React.js from module:
module.exports = React;
```

I’ve tried namespace merging, module augmentation, generating it from jsdoc, implementing the patch in the TS and generation from that, so far no luck

The end goal is somewhere in the TS module to be able to do something like this

```js
import React, { useState } from '@extended/react';

export const Component: React.FC = () => {
    // default import from patched module
    const [defaultImport] = React.useState(true);

    // named import from original reac module
    const [namedImport] = useState(true);

    return (
        <div>Negocios son los negocios</div>
    );
};

// default import with added react dom
React.ReactDom.render(<Component />, document.body);

// default import with added new component
class C extends React.ExtendedComponent {

}
```

Maybe someone knows how to do it properly?